# Powershell command to get all the users in domains

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, domain

Is there any command or script to get all the users belonging to any domains in SharePoint 2010. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need domain users from any specific SharePoint site collection?...

Comment: yes hardik am looking for domain users from SP site collection.

Comment: Please look at below answer .... It will help you...

Comment: To the Stackexchange admins the users whoever have marked this down as not related to SharePoint it is related to SharePoint as I clearly asked in my question doamin belonging to SharePoint and there is the finding below with the reply for my question. I request this whether it can be revoking in removing negative points of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use below snippet
>
> ```
> Get-SPUser -Web http://server/sites/yoursite | Where { $_.IsDomainGroup }
> ```
>
> AD group is treated as a special user. So this can be find using the
>   filter IsDomainGroup
>
> ```
> $SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication https://*******.com/
>
> foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
> {
>     write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$SPsite.RootWeb.Title 
>     ##write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$SPsite.RootWeb.URL
>     $SiteURL = $SPsite.RootWeb.URL
>     $ADgroup=Get-SPUser -Web $SiteURL -Limit ALL | Where { $_.IsDomainGroup }
>     foreach($group in $ADgroup)
>     {
>         if($Output -notcontains $group.DisplayName)
>         {
>             write-host $group.DisplayName
>             $Output += ($group.DisplayName)
>             $users = new-object psobject
>             $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Site Collection" -value $SPsite.RootWeb.Title
>             $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Groups" -value $group.DisplayName
>             $combinedusers += $users
>         }
>     } 
>     $combinedusers | export-csv "F:\group.csv" -notypeinformation
> }
> ```